# Bind from any request input: FromQuery, FromRoute, FromForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core, I need the ViewModel members to be data bound to the incoming request data. I don't care if it comes from Form post, Query string or Route param.

It seems there are new attributes for each of these sources, but not one that handles them all.

```
[FromQuery(Name="xyz")] // Works only with query string
[FromForm(Name="xyz")] // Works only with form data
[FromRoute(Name="xyz")] // Works only with route data
public string Something {get; set;}
```

Is there any way to support all of them?

Comment: If you didn't add these attributes, doesn't the `DefaultModelBinder` take care of this? It would look for `Something` in Form values, Route values and Query strings, **in that order**. ([Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#how-model-binding-works))

Comment: Yes it does, but if the parameter name is the same as the property name. But if you need to bind a different param name and still benefit from the default behaviour as you said, apparently there is no way now, which is a shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The declaration is explicit. You must choose to take it from the query string, the request body, or the URL.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I wonder what happens if you specify all of those attributes?!

Comment: Honestly, not sure. Never tried. Generally speaking, there's very little need to allow multiple if you're designing routes properly. For example, a POST should pretty much always utilize `FromBody` or `FromForm`. `FromQuery` would be totally inappropriate. Whereas, with a GET, there is no request body, so any data would necessarily need `FromQuery`. `FromRoute`, in my experience, is superfluous. If the param is defined in the route, it ends up in the right place, regardless of whether you decorate it with the `FromRoute` attribute.